# Powershell Remote PSSession Failing - Domain Administrator Account

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I am troubleshooting an issue I have with a PRTG sensor not collecting Windows Update information from one of our servers. It is using WinRM and a remote PowerShell command to do that.

Server 1 - Issue Server

Server 2 - Working Server

When I try to use `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1` or `winrs -r:Server1 dir` to test the connection I keep getting the following errors:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> winrs -r:Server1 dir


Winrs error:WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server Server1 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Server1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

If I run the command on any of our other servers the connection is successful, this is the only one giving me trouble.

If I run the command `Enter-PSSession` with the `-Credential` switch with my user account I get the same error, but if I run the command and specify the local administrator account of the server it will connect. Other servers work fine.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -Credential Server1\administrator
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> exit

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -credential domain\myuser
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server Server1 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -credential alpenaw2k.local\kemp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Server1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server2
[Server2]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> exit
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

If I run `New-PSSession` from the local server I will get the same error, unless I specify the `-EnableNetworkAccess` switch and then it will connect. This confuses me. Event viewer gives me Event ID 161 related to user authentication and error 142 for the session failing to create.

If I run `Test-WSMan` from the local server and a remote host it shows it running.

Here is the WinRM config and the listener config:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = 10.10.10.142
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647

PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.10.10.87, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::4579:db85:c9cb:ead0%6
```

Other things I have tried:

- I have no GPO settings in place for WinRM.
- I have deleted and recreated the listener.
- I have reset the config of WinRM several times.
- Windows Advanced Firewall is disabled for Public, Private, and Domain
  networks.
- I have checked the `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI` permissions and the
  privileges seem okay.
- I have used IP addresses instead of hostnames with the same
  results.
- I have added my computer to the trusted host list and it does not
  work. This shouldn't be necessary though as the both the computers
  are on the same domain.
- Ran `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` (Although this should be unnecessary
  as WinRM is enabled by default for Server 2012 and forward).
- I have added my user to the Local Administrators and Remote
  Management Users on the server with no luck.
- I have adjusted the registry of `REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1` and this does not
  work regardless of its value.
- I have rebooted and ran an `sfc /scannow` as a last ditch effort.

Specs of the server, workstation, and my user:

- My domain account is a Domain Administrator.
- Server is Windows Server 2019 Standard.
- Workstation is Windows 10 Pro.
- PowerShell Version 5 for both.
- Both computers are on the same domain.
- Both computers are up to date.

I could use the local administrator account to poll this information and fix my intimidate problem, but that doesn't fix the underlying issue.

EDIT:

From the remote server there are no error entries in the Windows Remote Management Log, but on my computer I have these:

Error Event ID - 142

```
WSMan operation Enumeration failed, error code 2150858909
```

Error Event ID - 49

```
The WinRM protocol operation failed due to the following error: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config..
```

Error Event ID - 161

```
WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config.
```

I can RDP into the server just fine, that's how I have been doing some of the local tests.

I tested these two commands:

`gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName Server1` executes normally with no issue, that's specifying the remote server and RDPing to running locally.

`Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName Server1` I cannot run from my workstation, but If I RDP into the sever and run it, it will execute normally.

Comment: Can you authenticate with the same user on other services like rdp or wmi/rpc? Try out both `gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername Server1` and `Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -computername Server1` without `-Credential`. Are you able to try another client machine to connect with?

Comment: Can you add the event log details as well? They can have good detail about extra weird issues like: https://serverfault.com/a/580412/411612

Comment: I can RDP into the server just fine, that's how I have been doing some of the local tests.

I tested the two commands listed and for the `gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername Server1` command it executes normally with no issue, that's specifying the remote server and RDPing to running locally. 

For the `Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -computername Server1` I cannot run it from my workstation, but If I RDP into the sever and run it, it will execute normally.

Comment: I have added the events to the main question

Comment: I think this post really needs to go to https://serverfault. Dev tools and programs commonly used by devs are on topic here *to a point* but this really exceeds the assistance a programming Q&A site can reasonably offer. There are *a ton* of things that can be wrong here, and Kerberos auth failures can be difficult to debug.

Comment: I will say this, assuming your remote server is on the domain, your local system also needs to be on the domain (or you use basic auth but I don't recommend that without *at least* using winrm over ssl). you can't force NTLM auth and GPO may prevent negotiating an NTLM fallback for an unverified client

Comment: Some other general jank krb troubleshooting to try: check `setspn -L Server1` and see if anything weird got registered compared to Server2. Also check the output of `klist` on your PC for whether you've got valid tokens.

Comment: I will re-post there if its more appropriate and add what I found with the SPN's.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I got it resolved.

It was an SPN issue. The HTTP/Server1 and HTTP/Server1.domain were being used by a random user account named after the server.

After disabling the account and moving the SPN's to the computer object WinRM is now working like its supposed to.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/877459/remote-powershell-not-working-but-test-wsman-does) helped get me in the wright direction.